# Building a JS Function to dynamically create HTML elements and nest them inside each other

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I've created the below function to 
dynamically create HTML elements and append them wherever I want. The console doesn't log any errors when it runs, but the second element (`<p>`)
doesn't write to the document.

I'm thinking the error is something related to the "createdDiv" variable, but I haven't been able to isolate what is going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
//Array of elements to be created

var createdElements = [
    [ 'div', 'Class0', 'ID0'],
    ['p', 'Class1', 'ID1']      
];


//function to create and append elements to document

function createHTML( typeOfCreatedElement ,createdElementClass, createdElementId, locationForCreatedElement ){
    var createdElement = document.createElement( typeOfCreatedElement );
    createdElement.className = createdElementClass;
    createdElement.id = createdElementId;

    locationForCreatedElement['appendChild']( createdElement );

    return createdElement;
}


//run function 2x; 
//createdDiv successfully writes to the document, but createdParagraph disappears into a black hole...

var createdDiv = createHTML( createdElements[0][0], createdElements[0][1], createdElements[0][2], document.body );
var createdParagraph = createHTML( createdElements[1][0], createdElements[1][1], createdElements[1][2], createdDiv );
```

Comment: Could you please formulate a jsfiddle? :)

Comment: Actually [your code seems to work as it is](http://jsfiddle.net/0gmz30ny/). To see the paragraph on a page, you need to add some content to it.

Answer (score 1):

can you try with this update createHTML method()

```
function createHTML( typeOfCreatedElement ,createdElementClass, createdElementId, locationForCreatedElement ){
    var createdElement = document.createElement( typeOfCreatedElement );
    createdElement.className = createdElementClass;
    createdElement.id = createdElementId;
    createdElement.innerHTML = "this is a sample text for element type " + typeOfCreatedElement;

    locationForCreatedElement.appendChild( createdElement ); //line that I have changed.

    return createdElement;
}
```

[appendChild](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) is a method, not a property.

Comment: OP seems to use `appendChild` like a method in their code. Using dot notation instead of bracket notation doesn't change anything.

Comment: I added a fiddle link in my comment to OP's post. Their code seems to work.

Comment: @Teemu okay, I have added the innerHTML property as per your suggestion in your comment. All credit to you for detecting this.

Comment: Hey! Where is my credit, I haven't got anything ; ). Just a joke, inresponsive questionnaires are a sort of a plague at SO.